# Firebase app check: all requests are unverified on android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

App check keeps getting unverified requests with a flutter app running on android after I've followed the [android section of the firebase flutter doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider#android).

What I've done:

- Added the debug token in firebase app_check sections.
- Allowed both safety net and play integrity
- Kept this snippet:

```
    await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      androidProvider:
          kDebugMode ? AndroidProvider.debug : AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    );
```

Still

[image]

---

As per the comment it seems like point 1 isn't clear: I did add the debug token to firebase console in the android section:

[image]

Comment: have you followed these steps?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers#next_steps

Comment: @Rahul I'm using app check in debug environmnet as said in the post I added the debug token, but I did not enforce app check verification, as if I do, I'd be blocked since no request is being verified as per the picture posted.

Comment: There is a way for debug mode. You can add the string printed in debug mode to firebase console.

Comment: @Rahul This is what I did already as said in the post and in the comment above.